# how to increment day by one to find the next desired day in laravel

Tags: laravel

I've an array of day name like `['Wednesday','Sunday','Monday']`
now I want to find the next available dates That matched with the array from today's date. I want date. I tried for so long but none of them were successful. My code is given below

```
$datesAvailable = array();
$count = 0;

$dateToday = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();

//$avlDays is the array of day names
$avlDays = DB::table('doctor_schedules')
                ->select('available_days')
                ->where('department',$receivedDepartment)                                
                ->Where('doctor_id', $receivedDoctor)
                ->get();

for($k=5; $k > 0; $k++) 
{

    $dateToday = $dateToday->endOfWeek();
    // $parsedDate = Carbon::parse($dateToday);
    $dateTodayFormated = new Carbon($dateToday);
    $nextDayName = $dateTodayFormated->englishDayOfWeek;

    for($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++)
    {
        if($avlDays === $nextDayName)
        {
            $datesAvailable[$count] = $nextDayName;
            $count++;
        }
    }
}

return (['availableDates' => $dateToday]);
```

**Solved**

Comment: why are you storing `available_days` as a string in you database, you can use the day index instead `date('N')` will return "ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week" wich is from 1 to 7

Answer (score 0):

For the current date use

```
now()
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-now

Answer (score 0):

Carbon does this.

```
foreach ($avlDays as $day) {
    $nextDay = Carbon::parse("next $day");

    // do something with $nextDay...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming `$avlDays` is returning you a Carbon date range:

```
$avlDays = DB::table('doctor_schedules')
    ->select('available_days')
    ->where('department',$receivedDepartment)
    ->Where('doctor_id', $receivedDoctor)
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

The code below assumes that the array value from `['monday', 'tuesday' ...]` is saved as `$weekday`.

If you are trying to find a specific date within a range that falls on a certain weekday, you can do something like:

```
$availableAppointments = [];
foreach ($avlDays as $day) {
    if ($day->isDayOfWeek($weekday)) {
        $availableAppointments[] = $day;
    }
```

Then you can use `$availableAppointments` to list out the available dates on that day of the week.

Comment: see image description please

Comment: @Ajmal-Hossain will it only ever return one day? What happens when there's more than 1 day?

Comment: Solved in my own way